# Want to make interface Serializable

Tags: android, interface, serializable

My problem is want to send interface instance to camera activity so that in `onActivityResult` I can call method of that interface implementation. I tried following logic that make custom interface made `serializable` but got error.

I just want to know proper way to make custom interface serializable, I used below code

```
public interface ImageListener extends Serializable{
    public void onImageCaptureResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data);
}
```

Implementation is in my fragment

```
ImageListener imageListener = new ImageListener() {
    @Override
    public void onImageCaptureResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        displayToast("image got in fragment ");
    }
};
```

but when I put instance of interface in `intent.putExtra` like this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
intent.putExtra("il",imageListener); // ERROR AT THIS LINE
getActivity().startActivityForResult(intent, ConstantsTags.REQUEST_CAMERA);
```

I got Exception `java.io.NotSerializableException`.

Please guide me how can I achieve this.

Comment: Why do you even need to pass your interface here. `onActivityResult` will be called with same request code. When you hit that part call your interface method like `imageListener.onImageCaptureResult(...)`

Comment: because imageListener is implemented in my fragment and onActivityResult call back fall in activity.

Comment: Call your Fragment's `onActivityResult` then. See this how to do that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6147884/onactivityresult-not-being-called-in-fragment

Comment: I have followed those steps but in onActivityResult the request code is changed when i called startActivityForResult in fragment . but when i use getActivity().startActivityForResult(); then i got right request code.
But with super call i didn't receive call back in fragment's onActivityResult

Comment: Thanks Rohit i got solution. i called with getActivity().startActivity and in onActivityResult call fragments custom method